# Why Do We Say "The Same"?

Tags: english, grammar

Generally, sentences are constructed like this:

```
Compared to Joe, he looks similar.
Compared to Joe, he looks different.
Compared to Joe, he looks handsome.
Compared to Joe, he looks ugly.
```

Yet, when it comes to "same", a sentence would be considered ungrammatical if it was written as:

```
Compared to Joe, he looks same.
```

Instead, it should be written as:

```
Compared to Joe, he looks the same.
```

Is there a reason for this quirk?

EDIT:

I'm interested in the "why" of this topic. I wonder if this peculiar treatment of "same" developed due to functors that are synonymous with "same", such as "as". Just as functors are somewhat special in grammar, I wonder if that inclined special use of "same" in grammar too.

Comment: Related ELU question: [Can you use “same” without “the”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235076)

Comment: Where "the same" is a predicative, we normally use "the", which serves as a dependent of the adjective, i.e. "the" modifies "same".

Comment: The appropriate question in linguistics is, what is a good and linguistically sophisticated part-of-speech analysis of the word "same".

Comment: A linguistically sophisticated analysis would not attempt to pin an unchanging POS label on a word like _same_, which is more part of the grammar than the lexicon. As Wittgenstein put it, "What causes most trouble in philosophy is that we are tempted to describe the use of important 'odd-job' words as though they were words with regular functions."

Comment: @sumelic Thanks, but that page answered the "how" of this phenomenon, but not the "why". I wonder if this peculiar treatment of "same" developed due to functors that are synonymous with "same", such as "as". Just as functors are somewhat special in grammar, I wonder if that inclined special use of "same" in grammar too.

Comment: @jlawler That's beautifully put!

Comment: @abcjme You didn't ask what part of speech it is. But I can tell you that "same" is an adjective and "the" is a determinative that modifies it. That "same" is an adjective is evident from the fact that it can be modified by "very" ("the very same as ...").  **Always** look for the evidence. What is so difficult about that?

Comment: @abcjme: the whole of the answer to nearly all question about language that start "why" is "Because that's the way it is". Language happens, over centuries and millenian. It is almost never consciously moulded. We can explain _how_ some change happened, but in most cases there's no real answer to _why_ that change happened (and others didn't).

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is something interesting with "same". In Old English, it was (almost?) invariably part of the construction `swa sama`, "in the same way". It has thus always been "bound" to something.

Its use after the definite article "the" or the determiners "this" or "that" moved `same` into the environment of Old English `self` and `ilca`, as "intensifiers" by the time of Middle English:

> *And **the same** Salomon seith that ‘he that travailleth and bisieth hym to tilien his land shal eten breed...*
>
> And that same Salomon said that ‘he who works and keeps himself busy to work his land will eat bread...
>
> *The Tale of Melibee* from *The Canterbury Tales*, G. Chaucer (~1400)

One can even find examples of `the` + `ilca` having coalesced into one new determiner, and have `same` after it. Hence the following remark of Bremark (2010) concerning Middle English:

> In these examples, *the same* is as a unit used as a sort of personal pronoun signalling anaphoric relations of identity within the text, equivalent to the endophoric uses of *it*, *them*, and to a lesser extent *he*.

Answer (score -1):

Because in the sentence

> Compared to Joe, he looks similar.

"similar" is an adjective, related to "he", while in

> Compared to Joe, he looks the same.

"the" and "same' are related to an omitted but implied noun "person", "man", etc.